# Get profile picture from facebook graph api using javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

When i try to get facebook profile picture using facebook graph api, it was showing that response.data in undefined. 
here is code to get profile picture

```
  FB.api('/me/picture?width=180&height=180', function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                     document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "<img src=" +response.data.url+ ">";
    });
```

And the html will be

```
<div id="status"></div>
```

here is my graph explorer image

[image]

What i'm doing wrong, please can anyone guide mee..

thanks in advance

when i console the response object

It showing like this

```
error: {…}
​​
code: 1
​​
error_subcode: 1357046
​​
message: "Received Invalid JSON reply."
​​
type: "http"
```

Comment: What does console.log return?

Comment: response.data is undefined

Comment: i updated my question

Answer (score -1):

Please retry with following code:

```js
FB.api(
  '/me/picture',
  'GET',
  {},
  function(response) {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "<img src=" +response.data.url+ ">";
  }
);
```